# Problems using array in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I modified this script so it would work over multiple directories. However when I run the script, I get an error message at line 6, char 3 "Invalid procedure call or argument".  I'm new to VB scripting, but I would think that I can call a function with a variable as its argument.

```
Dim loc(2)
loc(0) = "C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Temp\"

for each path in loc
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set folder = fso.GetFolder(path)

  ' delete all files in root folder
  for each f in folder.Files
     On Error Resume Next
     name = f.name
     f.Delete True
     If Err Then
       'WScript.Echo "Error deleting:" & Name & " - " & Err.Description
     Else
       'WScript.Echo "Deleted:" & Name
     End If
     On Error GoTo 0
  Next

  ' delete all subfolders and files
  For Each f In folder.SubFolders
     On Error Resume Next
     name = f.name
     f.Delete True
     If Err Then
       'WScript.Echo "Error deleting:" & Name & " - " & Err.Description
     Else
       'WScript.Echo "Deleted:" & Name
     End If
     On Error GoTo 0
  Next
Next
```

Comment: Is this the complete code

Comment: @ niz this is what the loc has.it will execute only for the first loop `(0): "C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Temp\" (1): Empty (2): Empty`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring an array whose highest index is 2. That'll be an array with three items: zero, one, and two. Then you're initializing only one of the items in that array, item zero. The first time through the loop, it's fine. The second time, it takes the second item from the array and sets `path` equal to it. That second array item is equal to `Nothing`, because you never initialized it to anything else, so `path` then equals `Nothing`. `fso.GetFolder(path)` fails when `path` equals `Nothing`.

When I change the array declaration to loc(0), it has just one item, item zero. And then your code works fine for me.

```
Dim loc(0)
```

That declaration looks surreally counterintuitive to me, but the compiler likes it.

Alternatively, you could initialize all three items in your original array:

```
loc(0) = "C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Temp\"
loc(1) = "C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Temp\blah"
loc(2) = "C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Temp\foobar"
```

...or whatever. But those paths should be real directories, otherwise `fso.GetFolder()` will fail because they don't exist. That error would look like this:

```
path.vbs(8, 3) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Path not found
```

Comment: Thanks!!  Makes sense and I should have checked the directory to see if items were deleted.